# my app widget is not showing on home screen

Tags: android, android-widget

I add Widget functionality to my app but whenever I try to add a widget to the home screen it opens configuration activity.

after setting widget from configuration activity is got closed but the widget is not added to homescreen.

here my code:

> AlwaysAlive.xml (AppWidgetProvider class)

```
package com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.nativehandle.D;
import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.nativehandle.L;
import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.nativehandle.Q;
import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.nativehandle.S;
import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.nativehandle.T;
import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.nativehandle.W;
import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.nativehandle.X;
import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.services.ForegroundService;
import com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.utilitis.HelperClass;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class AlwaysAlive extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Native");
    }

    HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass();
    RemoteViews remoteViews;

    public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                       int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.always_alive);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlwaysAlive.class);
        intent.setAction("ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE_FROM_WIDGET");

        if (T.D() || T.L() || T.S() || T.W() || T.SE()) {
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.app_widget_imageView, R.drawable.color_icon);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.app_widget_textView, "ON");
            remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.app_widget_textView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            Intent intentImageStampService = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(intentImageStampService);
            } else {
                context.startService(intentImageStampService);
            }
        }

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app_widget_imageView, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Log.e("CORONA", "onEnabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);
        Log.e("CORONA", "onDisabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.e("CORONA", "onReceive");
        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE_FROM_WIDGET")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.always_alive);
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

                if (!helperClass.isMyServiceRunning(ForegroundService.class, context)) {
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.app_widget_imageView, R.drawable.color_icon);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.app_widget_textView, "ON");
                    views.setTextColor(R.id.app_widget_textView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Intent intentImageStampService = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        context.startForegroundService(intentImageStampService);
                    } else {
                        context.startService(intentImageStampService);
                    }
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context,
                            AlwaysAlive.class), views);
                    D.T(X.A());
                    L.T(X.B());
                    S.T(X.C());
                    W.T(X.D());
                    S.SET(X.SE());
                    if (!T.D() && !T.L() && !T.S() && !T.W() && !T.SE()) {
                        D.T(true);
                        Q.A(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("Else_SPEEEEEEE", "Else_SPEEEEE333333333333333");
                    Q.A(T.D());
                    Q.B(T.L());
                    Q.C(T.S());
                    Q.D(T.W());
                    Q.SE(T.SE());

                    D.T(false);
                    L.T(false);
                    S.T(false);
                    W.T(false);
                    S.SET(false);

                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.app_widget_imageView, R.drawable.greyicon);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.app_widget_textView, "OFF");
                    views.setTextColor(R.id.app_widget_textView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wOff));
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, AlwaysAlive.class), views);
                    Intent intentImageStampService = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
                    context.stopService(intentImageStampService);
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals("ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE_FROM_WIDGET_SP")) {
                Log.e("Else_SP", "Else_SP");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }


    public void uFromSOFF(Context context) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.always_alive);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.app_widget_imageView, R.drawable.greyicon);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.app_widget_textView, "OFF");
        views.setTextColor(R.id.app_widget_textView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.wOff));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context,
                AlwaysAlive.class), views);
        if (helperClass.isMyServiceRunning(ForegroundService.class, context)) {
            Intent intentImageStampService = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
            context.stopService(intentImageStampService);
        }

    }


    public void uFromSON(Context context) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.always_alive);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.app_widget_imageView, R.drawable.color_icon);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.app_widget_textView, "ON");
        views.setTextColor(R.id.app_widget_textView, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context,
                AlwaysAlive.class), views);
        if (!helperClass.isMyServiceRunning(ForegroundService.class, context)) {
            Intent intentImageStampService = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
            context.startService(intentImageStampService);
        }

    }
}
```

> always_alive_info.xml(appwidget-provider)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure="com.autostamper.datetimestampphoto.activity.InAppBillingActivity"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/always_alive"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/always_alive"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/color_icon"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"></appwidget-provider>
```

> InAppBillingActivity.java(Configuration activity)

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (J.O() != 0) {
            Context context = InAppBillingActivity.this;
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            AlwaysAlive.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue if you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code in onResume() method:

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                        AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            }

            if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                finish();
                return;
            }

            Context context = Legolas.this;

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            AlwaysAlive.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);

            finish();
```